# New admin for MS Access, how to modify existing macro

Tags: ms-access

I'm a new admin for an MS access database.  I'm very new to MS Access so please forgive me if I ask something that does not make sense here....

The current staff has a small (5MB or so) .mdb file on their desktop.  Clicking that file opens access and lists queries on the left hand side of Access.  I've copied this file to my laptop in an effort to start working/maintaining the databaser.  However clicking any query yields in an error (vice loading/running) that essentially says the network location (file) cannot be found.

The .mdb file on their desktops includes macros to load the main .mdb file (much bigger at 33MB) via a network share.  Yet when I open this .mdb file from my desktop and view the macros via the macro tab I do not see any macro that tries to load the .mdb file from the network share.  Additionally some of the macros fail.  One in particluar is trying to load the main .mdb file over the network share.  I have the main .mdb file on my desktop and would like to change, amongst other things, that macro to point to the local copy vs. the network copy to which the macro points.  What is the best way to view all macros in an .mdb file of this nature with the intent on modifying them as needed?

EDIT:

I should also mention that I have a new version of Access on my laptop (2010).  Everyone else is using 2003.  Unfortunatley I am unable to install the old version on my laptop due to corporate policy.  As people use the database regulary I ideally need to modify the .mdb file on my laptop which runs 2010...

Comment: Have you watched one of those staff show you what "macros" they are running? Have you looked at the network share to see what mdb file is there, that supposedly gets loaded?

Comment: I know where the file is (mapped drive and location), I just don't see it referenced anywhere unless I click on the query on the left...

Comment: Because you're much more likely to have success with this particular _programming related_ question on [so] than on [dba.se] I'm shoving your question over there. We are all about getting the best eyes on questions, and unfortunately for you, this site caters to folks who have to devote entire servers to databases, not really the kind that fit on my 10 year old USB keys ... :-\ So off you go to [so] and better eyeballs for your troubles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I doubt you're having macro or VBA problems.

What is far more likely is that the tables you see listed on the left hand of the screen are actually "Attached" tables which reside in the other database on the network.

If this is the case, the icon just to the left of each table name will have a small arrow.

You say you now have a copy of the larger database locally on your PC, so what you need to do is to is go to the smaller DB, and under "External Data" choose "Linked Table Manager."

Select all of the tables which show they are attached to the server version of the larger DB, choose "Always Prompt for New Location" and click "OK."

You will be given an "Open File Dialogue" which will allow you to browse to your *local* copy of the larger database. Simply click on that file name and click "OK" or "Done" or whatever button means you're done.

Comment: When I try to click the "Linked Table Manager" it says the wizard is not installed or in a bad state.  I should note when I try to open the smaller .mdb file both the access and Visual Basic for Applications Tool open.  The VB window is throwing a compile error as well saying it cannot find the TableDef.  I am assuming it cannot find the networked database?  I should also mention that I have a new version of Access on my laptop (2010), everyone else is using 2003....

Comment: That sounds like a missing reference in the VBA project. Try opening the VBA Editor (Alt-F11), go to Tools -> References, and see if there are any missing references.

Comment: Hmmm, Tools->References is greyed out!  Should that be?  Also, I do not have the ability to open VBA editor on my own.  Whenever I try to open the mbd file in question the VBA editor comes up automatically with the compile error.

Comment: Ah, I did finally get the Tools menu to come up.  I had to open everything, let it error out, close the VBA editor, then re-open it.  Now, how do I know is a reference is missing in this list?

Comment: If you scroll up and down the list of references it should say 'MISSING: ' before the reference. See http://www.cpearson.com/excel/missingreferences.aspx for some example images. I'd also look for references which cause problems with Access 2010 like calender objects using common dialog, etc.

Answer (score 1):

It is common to split an Access application into front-end (code, forms, etc) and back-end (data). The back-end tables are then linked to the front-end. This can be done at run time.

When you say macros, do you mean macros or code modules? If you mean macros, they will be listed under macros in the database window, if you mean code, you may see modules listed, which you can open and modify. A good place to find the code to link tables will be in an autoexec macro or a start-up form.

Comment: I'm wondering if it's not really 'loading' data from the back end, but just has a linked table attached.

Comment: @Beth That is certainly possible, but the OP does mention that macros are involved.

Comment: yes, but that could be the autoexec macro and OP, being new to Access, could be misinterpreting what's going on