# What reference is needed for TableDef object in Access 2010

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2003

I'm trying to use a macro/.mdb file that was written in Access 2003 in a new Access 2010 Access install.  Opening my file I get a compile error saying the `TableDef` object is not able to be found.  When I check my Tools->References menu I see Microsoft DAO 3.6 Object Library as available, shouldn't that suffice?  Or is something else needed for the `TableDef`?

Comment: The DAO library for Access 2007 and 2010 is `Microsoft Office x.x Access Database Engine Object Library`, not `Microsoft DAO 3.6 Object Library`

Comment: I enabled that library but I am still getting the same compile error...

Comment: You must prefix TableDef with "DAO", ex. Dim td as DAO.TableDef.

Comment: Please post some code and mark the line causing the error. Do you have Option Explicit at the top of the module?

Comment: @rontornambe Since when?

Comment: I moved the Microsoft Office x.x Access Database Enginer Object Library up in priority and it no longer halts on that object.  So thanks!  It's not crashing on another object/method.  Is there a good srouce that shows the libraries needed for each object in Microsoft Access?

Comment: Remou, you should have made that an answer.  It solved my problem.  It may have uncovered others nut it solved my initial problem :)

Comment: Please close out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13809015/new-admin-for-ms-access-how-to-modify-existing-macro/13809768#comment19184806_13809768  if this is the answer to that issue as well. Danke.

Comment: This is not the answer to that question but after learning more about this environment I realize a correct answer was back on that page.  This question was just one part of that question and a very specific question.

Comment: No Remou you do not always have to prefix TableDef with DAO, but it is another way of resolving this type of conflict.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The DAO library for Access 2007 and 2010 is `Microsoft Office x.x Access Database Engine Object Library`, not `Microsoft DAO 3.6 Object Library`.