# DAO.TableDef not defined in excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I am trying to convert to  to five formats but when i execute the code on line 2
it  says DAO.TableDef is not defined.
If the code would run succesfully it would create five formats: csv,xml.laccdb, acccdb, xls.
The following programs is going to be created as new files in excel vba.

```
Sub exportTables2XLS()
Dim td As DAO.TableDef, db As DAO.Database
Dim out_file As String
out_file = CurrentProject.Path & "\test.xls"
Set db = CurrentDb()
For Each td In db.TableDefs
If Left(td.Name, 4) = "MSys" Then
'//do nothing -- skip
Else
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, _
td.Name, out_file, True, Replace(td.Name, "dbo_", "")
End If
Next
End Sub
'expeced ouput :test.xls, test.xml, test.csv, test.accdb,test.laccdb,
```

Comment: Is this VBA written in Excel or Access?

Comment: it is written in excel

Comment: That doesn't make too much sense. There is no `CurrentDb` and no `TableDefs` in Excel.

Comment: yeah it worked in access but the tip in excel helped me though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If its failing on your definition of the DAO.TableDef, then its probably your References

Alt + F11 > Tools > References

Make sure this is checked, where x is your specific version number: Microsoft DAO x.x Object Library

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13919392/4731063